# Show corresponding date on recurring reminder slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to show the corresponding date on the recurring reminder of slack.

Ex: /remind me "Today is dd/mm/yyyy" at 07:00AM every Tuesday

Now i want to see the current date in the message instead of dd, mm, yyyy on that corresponding day.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that via the remind command since Slack treats it as a message to send to. But you can definitely use the API to do so.

You can make a Cron Job that gets the date and formats it into the dd/mm/yy
or use a simple `chat.postMessage`

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer a bit more or direct me to some useful links for how to create the Cron job or how to use the API for remind command?

Comment: https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add This is the API Endpoint for creating Reminders so In your case you'll create a Cron job at every day at 7 O'Clock to increase the day or simply use chat.postMessage everyday at 7'O clock to message you which day it is